# Microsoft SQL Insert into subset of table columns fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can anyone help me find the column or columns in this table where data would be truncated?

I am trying to execute the SQL insert below, but it is failing with the error:

> String or binary data would be truncated.

Which I understand means a value is too big to be contained by a column in the table, but all of the values specified in my insert statement appear to be acceptable sizes for their columns.

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 my query is:

```
INSERT INTO cms_incident_report(cid, userid, rhid, catid)   
VALUES('2', '436', '68402', '4')`
```

I have traced the issue to that and I am not including the rest of the columns in my query, the table `cms_incident_report` has 54 columns, one of them is a primary key that increments automatically and the rest have the 'Allow null' enabled. If I run a query that inserts values in all the fields of that table it works, if I neglect one column it produces this error.

I'm using the same query on other tables successfully without the need to write all of the columns names but just the ones I want to insert and the rest is defaulted to NULL. It doesn't make much sense to me and I can't figure out the actual reason behind this error.

**EDIT**

The columns `cid, userid, rhid, catid` are of types `int, varchar(200), int, int`

Full table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cms_incident_report]
(
    [incident_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [cid] [int] NULL,
    [userid] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [rhid] [int] NULL,
    [catid] [int] NULL,
    [col1] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [col2] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [col3] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [col4] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [col5] [date] NULL,
    [col6] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [col7] [tinyint] NULL,
    [col8] [tinyint] NULL,
    [col9] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [col10] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [col11] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [col12] [date] NULL,
    [col13] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [col14] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [col15] [date] NULL,
    [col16] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [col17] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [col18] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [col19] [int] NULL,
    [col20] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [col21] [int] NULL,
    [col22] [date] NULL,
    [col23] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [col24] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [col25] [int] NULL,
    [col26] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [col27] [int] NULL,
    [col28] [date] NULL,
    [col29] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [col30] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [col31] [int] NULL,
    [col32] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [col34] [int] NULL,
    [col35] [date] NULL,
    [col36] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [col37] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [col38] [int] NULL,
    [col40] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [col41] [int] NULL,
    [col42] [date] NULL,
    [col43] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [col44] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [col45] [int] NULL,
    [col46] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [col47] [int] NULL,
    [col48] [date] NULL,
    [col49] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [status] [varchar](3) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [incident_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[cms_incident_report] ADD  DEFAULT ('0') FOR [col13]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[cms_incident_report] ADD  DEFAULT ('0') FOR [col42]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[cms_incident_report] ADD  DEFAULT ('Open') FOR [status]
GO
```

Comment: "I can't put the schema of the table for NDA reasons" - what's stopping you renaming columns? Post table's full schema if you want help.

Comment: Is there an insert trigger on this table?

Comment: At least provide the data-types in the order they appear and sample data in the order you are inserting that is causing the error. That way we can attempt a mismatch.

Comment: @GMastros nope there aren't any triggers on this table.

Comment: @EmacsUser I provided an edit and will provide the full schema in a couple of minutes once I change the names

Comment: So if you include all the fields it works? Does 'all fields' include the autoincrement PK field? I suggest you remove fields one at a time from your test script until you isolate the field in question. This is something you can complete without posting the table schema (or even asking on here)

Comment: You cant expect us to guess, show us how to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Just a thought from way out there - could there be a default constraint on one or more columns that specifies a value that would be truncated? Sometimes constraints get omitted as schemas change over time.

Comment: Show sample going into it. It is prob pretty obvious

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid If I include all fields it works, no they don't include the PK field, I removed one field at a time, removing any field will result in this error. I did this before I post this question.

Comment: Are there any constraints or triggers (per @G Mastros) on any of the columns?

Comment: @MarkLarter YES!! The error was in a default indeed, I included them in the question it turns out there's a default `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[cms_incident_report] ADD  DEFAULT ('Open') FOR [status]` for a col of varchar(3). Thanks for that.. for the record I didn't create this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for constraints or triggers that would attempt to insert a value too large for a given column. This can happen when over time schema changes occur, and constraints or triggers have escaped the scope of impact review along the way.

In this case (`varchar(3)`) column `status` had a default constraint that was attempting to put the four character value `'Open'` into the three character column.

Answer (score 2):

If those datatypes you provided are correct in your re-edits, then change the values line from:

```
VALUES('2','436','68402','4')
```

to

```
VALUES(2,'436',68402,4)
```

to match the types defined. This will take care of the truncated error message.

Another way to find if default values are being inserted, try this one line and then see which columns are being populated through other logic:

```
INSERT INTO cms_incident_report DEFAULT VALUES
```

Check all non-null columns.

Comment: Thanks but I tried that before, that didn't change the resulting error.